# loading contacts just like whatsapp

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-cursoradapter

I'm working on getting contact list in an activity. I want to retrieve contact photo for the contacts, if they have a profile pick, just like in whatsapp. In whatsapp, it loads the contact image even if I don't have photos of them in my mobile. Can anybody please guide regarding this part. I really needs this one. My part of coding is as below. I tried every possible way to get the contact photos. I'm using custom cursor adapter for loading contacts.

```
class contactAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

        String Name, phoneNumber;
        private Cursor cursor;
        private Context ccontext;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public contactAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            cursor = c;
            ccontext = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context arg1, Cursor arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            if (holder == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.contactsImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);
                holder.ContactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
                holder.contactCheck = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_check);
                view.setTag(holder);
                holder.contactCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        cb.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
//                      ContactPerson selected = (ContactPerson)cb.getTag();
                        Log.d("selcted", cb.getTag().toString());
                        if(cb.isChecked()){

                            phoneID.add(cb.getTag().toString());


                        }
                    }

                }); 
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,Long.parseLong(String.valueOf((cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID)))));
            Log.d("ImagePath", uri.toString());
            InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ccontext.getContentResolver(), uri);
            Bitmap photo =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            holder.contactsImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
            holder.ContactName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            holder.contactCheck.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)));
            holder.contactCheck.setChecked(false);


        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox_item, arg2, false);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          Log.d("don't know", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
            return super.getView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Whatsapp is showing the profile picture of your contacts not from your phone, but they are ones the users have set to their own whatsapp profile.

Comment: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/1/

Comment: @nikvs: Thanks. Now I got the point. Could you please tell me where exactly contacts image is stored in mobile. Because in my Samsung mobile contacts having image will be displayed in contactslist. But I'm unable to retrieve those images also.

Comment: There is a Uri for that, check the above link I posted its a comprehensive guide for the same.

Comment: @user2955143 Why did you self-vandalise your question?

Answer (score 1):

It is already been asked before. If you want to load contact images the code for it is as follows

```
public Uri getPhotoUri(String contactId) {
            try {
                Cursor cur = ccontext.getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId + " AND "
                                + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"
                                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                        null);
                if (cur != null) {
                    if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
                        return null; // no photo
                    }
                } else {
                    return null; // error in cursor process
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long
                    .parseLong(contactId));
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        }
```

and check if the returned result contain contact image uri like this

```
 Uri u = getPhotoUri(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)));
            if (u != null) {
                    holder.contactsImage.setImageURI(u);
            } else {
                    holder.contactsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
```